# Wildfly 14 + EAR not disabled in case of heavy data processing

Tags: wildfly, activemq-artemis

Environment : Wildfly 14 + External Apache ActiveMQ Artemis 2.7

There are around 1 million messages accumulated on artemis queue. Created one ear having MDB listening to that queue. Deployed and Enable the ear thru wildfly admin console. MDB start receiving messages. After sometime tried to disabled application but I am not able to disabled application thru wildfly admin console as there is heavy data processing going on.

Can someone provide the solution

Comment: You need to provide more detail. *Why* are you not able to disable the application through the Wildfly admin console? What is the MDB doing specifically?

Comment: MDB is contentiously receiving messages and store into database. Also we have a job that will fetch data from the database as per define batch size and process it and send it to messaging queue.